Should we allow PKI related questions?
If I take a look at our Tour this crypto site is for questions about:

Asymmetric and symmetric cryptographic algorithms
Cryptographic protocols and cryptanalysis techniques
Hashing
Entropy and information theory
Random number generation

although above is just a sample of course.
Should we allow Public Key Infrastructure related issues or should we close them (if unanswered) or migrate them to the IT Security site? 

Meta-meta question: I could create two community wiki answers to create a "vote". Should I do this?

I would only create one answer, describing you opinion and remove that part from the question. If somebody dislikes your answer, they can write the alternative and downvote yours.

In my opinion questions about PKI and key management are better asked at the IT Security site; that is: if they are mainly concerned about management (company rules, expiration dates etc). If they are about the algorithms or protocols used to accomplish PKI or key management however they could be on topic (i.e. we should not close them even when they are borderline off-topic, for instance if they are about chain verification).
This would still allow a lot of questions, which is good because we should be more concerned about answering questions than strict separation between IT security and crypto.

No other answers and only upvotes so I've accepted my own opinion as the best :P
